# MongoDB query inside a nested array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following collection in MongoDB:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "profile":{
    "name": "name",
    "age":45,
    "wishlist": [
        {"_id":1, "name":"a1"},
        {"_id":2, "name":"a2"},
        {"_id":3, "name":"a3"}
      ]
  }
}
```

What is the query in the Mongo Shell to find if `wishlist` has collection where `_id = 2` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you ony match against *one* field, you only have to express the path to your field using dot-notation:

```
> db.user.find({"profile.wishlist._id": 2})
```

As explained in the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index), for arrays (like `wishlist`) this will match a document if *any* subdocument in the array match the field value.

---

Please note that if you need to match against *several* fields, you need to use either:

- `$elemMatch` if all matching fields should belong to the *same* subdocument;
- *or* multiple fields expressed using the dot-notation if the various fields don't need to match against the same subdocument.

Please compare the output of those two queries to get a grasp on this:

```
> db.user.find({"profile.wishlist._id": 2, "profile.wishlist.name": "a1"})
//                                      ^                            ^^
//                              will return your document even if the was no 
//                              subdocument having both _id=2 and name=a1
```

```
> db.user.find({"profile.wishlist": {$elemMatch: { _id: 2, name: "a1"}}})
//                                                      ^         ^^
//                                         no result as there was no subdocument
//                                         matching  _both_ _id=2 and name=a1
```